# Electron : Menu redirect to component (with Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

This is my first project with Angular 4 and Electron for a desktop application.

I have override the electron menu but I don't know how to redirect to a component when click on a submenu item.

This is a part of my menu.

```
const template = [
{
    label: 'Options',
    submenu: [
        {label: 'Login', click(){goToAComponent();}},
        {label: 'Quitter', 'role': 'quit'}
    ]
}];
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Electron click handler send an event:

```
const template = [
{
   label: 'Options',
   submenu: [
     {label: 'Login', 
        click(){
          mainWindow.webContents.send('customEvent', customArg);
        }
     },
     {label: 'Quitter', 'role': 'quit'}
   ]
}];
```

and then in your Angular Controller, listen to that event:

```
var ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.on('customEvent', function(sender, customArg) {
  invokeYourActionHere();
});
```